# LUA: trying to remove a value from a table when it is found in another table

Tags: lua

I'm trying to delete a key and value from a table when it is found in another table. I've been using this so far but although it recognizes the duplicate, it always removes the last item in the table...

```
function get_key_for_value( t, value )
 for k,v in pairs(t) do
 if v==value then return k
 end
 return nil
 end
 end

 for k,v in pairs (Iranian_Protected_Groups) do
 v[6] = 0
 if Springfield_3_Target_Name == v[2] then
 v[6] = v[6] + 1
 if v[6] > 0 then
 local Key_To_Remove = get_key_for_value (Iranian_Protected_Groups, v)
 MESSAGE:New( "Shared target is "..v[2], 40):ToBlue()
 table.remove (Iranian_Protected_Groups, Key_To_Remove)
 end
 end
 end
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

First, you should format your code using standard indentation to make it easier to parse as a human reading the code:

```
function get_key_for_value(t, value)
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if v == value then
            return k
        end
        return nil
    end
end
```

Look carefully at the `for` loop. You will *never* get past the *first* iteration, because *every* iteration `return`s.

Your function is fixed if you move your `return nil` statement outside the loop. (Though for most purposes, is redundant, because generally no value is equivalent to returning `nil`).

Before, `Key_To_Remove` was `nil`. When passing `nil` as the index to remove in `table.remove`, Lua removes the last element. This is convenient when treating a list like a stack, but hid a bug for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much Curtis.. solved my problem with "--" !. Is there any situation where using the "return nil" would be useful?

Comment: It turns out that there is a difference between returning nothing and returning `nil`. You can see it with `select("#", (function () end)())` vs `select("#", nil)`. Normally you won't write Lua code that cares about the difference, but every built-in function (defined in C) does care, so sometimes you'll get slightly different behavior. However, this only applies if you're directly passing the function to another function. Once you save it into a variable, "nothing" becomes `nil`.